# How to get the value for key @int from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am Creating a NSDictionary and adding a key value pair as below

```
  NSDictionary* dictionary = @{ @0: @"I am the value" };
```

and retrieving the value as below

```
  NSString* value = [dictionary valueForKey:@0];
```

Application crashed for doing this, I don't understand the reason, I am giving the same data type and value.

What is the datatype of @0, I guess it is NSNumber, If not correct me.

Comment: You forgot to prepend `@` to the string "I am the value".

Comment: hey thanks for reply, I forgot to add it while typing.

Comment: so update your question.if it works then removed question

Comment: @Viraj I have updated

Comment: valueForKey is a KVC method not NSDictionary method!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's `NSNumber` type however the problem is somewhere else.

You should call [`objectForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:) instead of `valueForKey` which is mainly used for [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170).

```
NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:@0];
```

or better:

```
NSString *value = dictionary[@0];
```

Answer (score 1):

valueForKey: is not the proper method for what you are trying to achieve.

you should use:

```
NSString* value = [dictionary objectForKey:@0];
```

ValueForKey is for key value coding and expect a NSString as parameters